# I want to do the same transformation in Python as I did in Scala

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I'm new to Python.

**Scala Code:**

> rdd1 is in string format

```scala
rdd1=sc.parallelize("[Canada,47;97;33;94;6]", "[Canada,59;98;24;83;3]","[Canada,77;63;93;86;62]")



val resultRDD = rdd1.map { r =>
  val Array(country, values) = r.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "").split(",")
    country -> values
}.reduceByKey((a, b) => a.split(";").zip(b.split(";")).map {
  case (i1, i2) => i1.toInt + i2.toInt }.mkString(";"))
```

**Output:**

```
Country,Values  //I have puted the column name to make sure that the output should be in two column  
Canada,183;258;150;263;71
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're using `rdd` over `DataFrame` API? `rdd` API is notoriously obtuse in Python, so your solutions are more likely to get an answer in `pyspark` if you use `DataFrame` API instead. Can you also include the desired output as well?

Comment: Is the number of columns fixed for the integer values ?

Comment: @JayadeepJayaraman The **values** are in one column and the **country** in second column

Comment: I can only suggest the first step right now `import re; rdd2 = rdd1.map(lambda x: re.findall(r"[\w']+", x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** OP wants to use map instead of flatMap, so I adjusted `flatMap` to `map` by which, you just need to take the first item out of the list comprehension, thus `map(lambda x: [...][0])`.

**side-note**: The above change is valid only to this particular case when list comprehension returns a list with only one item. for more general cases, you might need two `map()`s to replace what flatMap() does.

One way with RDD is to use a *list comprehension* to strip, split and convert the String into a key-value pair, with Country as key and a tuple of numbers as value. Since we use list comprehension, so we take *flatMap* on the RDD element, then use *reduceByKey* to do the calculation and *mapValues* to convert the resulting tuple back into string:

```
rdd1.map(lambda x: [ (e[0], tuple(map(int, e[1].split(';')))) for e in [x.strip('][').split(',')] ][0]) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: tuple([ x[i]+y[i] for i in range(len(x))]) ) \
    .mapValues(lambda x: ';'.join(map(str,x))) \
    .collect()
```

output after flatMap:

```
[('Canada', (47, 97, 33, 94, 6)),
 ('Canada', (59, 98, 24, 83, 3)),
 ('Canada', (77, 63, 93, 86, 62))]
```

output after reduceByKey:

```
[('Canada', (183, 258, 150, 263, 71))]
```

output after mapValues:

```
[('Canada', '183;258;150;263;71')]
```

Comment: @DiwakarKumar, converted it from `flatMap` to `map`

Comment: I wanted to do without for loop in place of for loop i wanted to use map .....

Comment: @DiwakarKumar, list comprehension in python is very efficient than you thought. it's not related to `for` loop which often related to iterating the dataframe by rows.

Comment: @DiwakarKumar, the only thing you need to adjust with this code for your new question is to add a filter ` if x != 'Country,Values'` to exclude the title in the map function. `rdd.map(lambda x: [ (e[0], tuple(map(int, e[1].split(';')))) for e in [x.split(',')] if x != 'Country,Values' ][0])`.

Comment: I have done this using rdd ....this time i want to do this using spark sql

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

myRDD = sc.parallelize([('Canada', '47;97;33;94;6'), ('Canada', '59;98;24;83;3'),('Canada', '77;63;93;86;62')])

df = myRDD.toDF()

>>> df.show(10)
+------+--------------+
|    _1|            _2|
+------+--------------+
|Canada| 47;97;33;94;6|
|Canada| 59;98;24;83;3|
|Canada|77;63;93;86;62|
+------+--------------+


df.select(
        col("_1").alias("country"),
        f.split("_2", ";").alias("values"),
        f.posexplode(f.split("_2", ";")).alias("pos", "val")
    )\
    .drop("val")\
    .select(
        "country",
        f.concat(f.lit("position"),f.col("pos").cast("string")).alias("name"),
        f.expr("values[pos]").alias("val")
    )\
    .groupBy("country").pivot("name").agg(f.sum("val"))\
    .show()        

+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+                     
|country|position0|position1|position2|position3|position4|
+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Canada|    183.0|    258.0|    150.0|    263.0|     71.0|
+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: but i want to do this using only rdd

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using RDD's ? Dataframes are much more richer and the general direction of spark is to use Dataframes or Datasets.